# How to dynamically disable vertical swipe in PageView

Tags: flutter

I would like to find a way to update the physics param to disable the swipe action in a parent `PageView` from a child widget.

I am using `riverpod` for updating the state in a child widget when it builds to know when I should pass `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` to the `physics` param in a parent widget. But the thing is that this approach is causing my child widget to rebuild recursively, because this is making the `PageView` rebuild to update the physics param. So I really don't know what to do here.

I have this parent Widget that builds the PageView:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final _navBar = useProvider(bottomNavigationBarProvider);
  return PageView(
    physics: navBar.isSwipeBlocked ? const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() : null,
    controller: pageController,
    onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
    children: [
      Beamer(
        key: const Key('feed-tab'),
        routerDelegate: BeamerDelegate(locationBuilder: (state) => FeedLocation(state)),
      ), 
    ]
  )
}
```

And the child Widget that updates the state variable:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final _navBar = useProvider(bottomNavigationBarProvider.notifier);
  useEffect(() {
    Future.microtask(() => _navBar.blockSwipe());
  }, []);
  return Container(...);
}
```

So when `FeedLocation` loads, it updates `_navBar` in an attempt for disabling the scroll behavior. But as I mentioned, this causes the parent to rebuild and `FeedLocation` to build again and then the recursive state..

The idea was to be able to go to `FeedLocation`, disable the scroll, then when go back, enable it again, but I don't see a solution for that.

I think I did already what this guy suggested https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37510#issuecomment-738051469 using Riverpod

And I guess I am a similar situation as this guys from the same thread https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37510#issuecomment-864416592

Is anybody able to see a solution or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `null` as the secondary ScrollPhysics with `PageScrollPhysics()` and make sure to add `setState(() {});` when you update the `isSwipeBlocked` variable.

Comment: Hey @MindStudio. Replacing `null` by `PageScrollPhysics()` makes no difference since `physics` is nullable and there is a default. Also, I don't see what to use with setState and where exactly since I'm using riverpod for the isSwipeBlocked state. Could you, please, elaborate the `setState(() {});` usage ?

Comment: you call `setState(() {});` whenever you want to rebuild the widget tree of a stateful widget with new values. You have to rebuild the widget after changing the isSwipeBlocked value for the changes to take effect. You can call `setState(() {});` from anywhere inside the build function of a statefulWidget.

Comment: Hey @MindStudio, thanks. The thing is that I am already using riverpod and the call `_navBar.blockSwipe()` in the child already update the state as `_navBar` is a `StateNotifier` from riverpod, which causes the rebuild of the parent `PageView` which is causing the child to build again, and then the recursion, and that, my friend, is my problem :) I would say `blockSwipe()` is a kind of `setState` of riverpod. BTW, my widgets are `HookWidget`.